# Loop through all Workbooks and all Worksheets, format and copy to template

Tags: excel, vba

I have a template workbook that I want to run this code from.  The code is to loop through all the files in a directory, and loop through all the worksheets in each file. Within each worksheet, run a process that basically format the data, then copy paste to a worksheet within the template workbook where more formatting is done.

This code that I have works when there is only one worksheet in the file, but when there are more than one, the worksheet loop occurs on the template workbook instead of the files.

I've created the formatting code as a different macro to be Call upon.  I've tried adding the worksheet loop within the formatting macro, but get the same issue.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub testLoopTabs()
    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'to loop through all the sheets
    'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Show
        MyFolder =.SelectedItems(1)
        Err.Clear
    End With
    'stops screen updating, calculations, events, and status bar updates to help code run faster
    'you'll be opening and closing many files so this will prevent your screen from displaying that
    MemorySaveTrue
    'You can use this procedure instead 'This section will loop through and open each file in the folder you selected
    'and then close that file before opening the next file
    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
    Set  wb = ThisWorkbook  'to refer to the workbook containing the code Do While MyFile <> ""
    Set  wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)  'loop worksheet
    ' Begin the loop.
    For Each ws In wbCopy.Worksheets
            'run process
            'format data
            Rows("1:14").Select
            Selection.DeleteShift:=xlUp
            Range("A1").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Application.WindowState = xlMaximized
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            With Selection
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlGeneral
                .VerticalAlignment = xlBottom
                .WrapText = False
                .Orientation = 0
                .AddIndent = False
                .IndentLevel = 0
                .ShrinkToFit = False
                .ReadingOrder = xlContext
                .MergeCells = False
            End With
            Selection.UnMerge
            Columns("A:A").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            Range("A1").Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
            Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
            Columns("A:A").Select
            Selection.InsertShift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("A1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Market"
            Range("A2").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=MID(CELL(""filename"",R[-1]C),FIND(""]"",CELL(""filename"",R[-1]C))+1,255)"
            Range("A2").Select
            Selection.Copy
            With Range("B1")
                Range(.Cells(2, 0),.End(xlDown).Offset(0, -1)).Select
            End With
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            'format dates and text to column
            Columns("E:F").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            Selection.NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
            Columns("E:E").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("E1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            Columns("F:F").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("F1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
             'find Net Value column
            Dim cell As Range
            Dim I As Integer
            For I = 12 To 20
                If Cells(1, I).Value = "Net Amount" Then
                    Columns(I).Select
                    Selection.Cut
                    Columns("K:K").InsertShift:=xlToRight
                Else
                End If
            Next I

            'format numbers to general
            Columns("H:H").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("H1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            Columns("I:I").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("I1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            Columns("K:K").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("K1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            Columns("L:L").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("L1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
            Columns("M:M").Select
            Selection.TextToColumnsDestination:=Range("M1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1)), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
             'add Other Charges
            Columns("N:N").Select
            Selection.InsertShift:=xlToRight, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
            Range("N1").Select
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Other Charges"
            Range("N2").Select
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-7]=""B"",ROUND(RC[-3]-RC[-2]-RC[-1],2),ROUND(RC[-2]-RC[-3]-RC[-1],2))"
            Range("N2").Select
            If IsEmpty(Range("B3")) = False Then
                Range("N2").Select
                Selection.Copy
                With Range("M2")
                    Range(.Cells(2, 2),.End(xlDown).Offset(0, 1)).Select
                End With
                ActiveSheet.Paste
                Range("A2:N2").Select
                Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
                Selection.Copy
            Else
                Range("A2:N2").Copy
            End If

            'paste to brokertradefile
            wb.Worksheets("BrokerTradeFile").Activate
            Range("A6").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
            'end process
            wbCopy.Activate
            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
            MsgBoxws.Name
            Next ws

        MsgBoxwbCopy.Name
        wbCopy.CloseSaveChanges:=False
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    'turns settings back on that you turned off before looping folders
    MemorySaveFalse
End Sub

Sub MemorySave(isOn As Boolean)
    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not(isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not(isOn)
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not(isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False
End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of relying on `ActiveWorkbook`, use a workbook variable. `Dim wb as Workbook`, then `Set wb = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False)`. This gives you a reference to the workbook to then use.

Comment: I've amended the code to include the Dim wb as Workbook  and Set wb as commented about.  I then replaced all the ActiveWorkbook with with wb.  However it still doesn't work.  On the files that contains more than one worksheet, it just loops back to the first worksheet.

Comment: @Temujin81 can you update your code on your post? So we can help you further.

Comment: Agreed, can you share the `formattradefiledata` code?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I would do this:

```
Option Explicit
Sub testLoopTabs()

    Dim MyFolder As String, MyFile As String
    Dim wb As Workbook, wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet 'to loop through all the sheets

    'Opens a file dialog box for user to select a folder

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
       .AllowMultiSelect = False
       .Show
       MyFolder = .SelectedItems(1)
       Err.Clear
    End With

    'stops screen updating, calculations, events, and statsu bar updates to help code run faster
    'you'll be opening and closing many files so this will prevent your screen from displaying that
    MemorySave True 'You can use this procedure instead

    'This section will loop through and open each file in the folder you selected
    'and then close that file before opening the next file

    MyFile = Dir(MyFolder & "\", vbReadOnly)
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook 'to refer to the workbook containing the code

    Do While MyFile <> ""
        Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=MyFolder & "\" & MyFile, UpdateLinks:=False, ReadOnly:=True)
        'loop worksheet
         ' Begin the loop.
        For Each ws In wbCopy.Worksheets
            'run process
            Call formattradefiledata
            'end process

            ' The following line shows how to reference a sheet within
            ' the loop by displaying the worksheet name in a dialog box.
            MsgBox ws.Name
        Next ws
        MsgBox wbCopy.Name
        wbCopy.Close SaveChanges:=False
        MyFile = Dir
    Loop

    'turns settings back on that you turned off before looping folders
    MemorySave False

End Sub
Sub MemorySave(isOn As Boolean)

    Application.Calculation = IIf(isOn, xlCalculationManual, xlCalculationAutomatic)
    Application.EnableEvents = Not (isOn)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = Not (isOn)
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = Not (isOn)
    ActiveSheet.DisplayPageBreaks = False

End Sub
```

Note that I added another procedure for your memory managing(you only need to call the procedure with True to activate the memory saving options and call it back with false to turn everything back on).

When you reference workbooks and worksheets nothing can go wrong. In my code the workbook with the code is referenced as `wb`, the files which are being open are referenced as `wbCopy` and to loop through all the worksheets you can use `For Each ws In wbCopy.Worksheets` after you reference `ws As Worksheet`. Is like telling excel, for every worksheet in the sheets from the workbook `wbCopy`.

Comment: I've updated my code above to show my formatting process code (it is the codes in between the 'run process' and 'end process' notes).  It is something in here that is making it not work. As when I use Damian's codes above with a simple formatting process it works fine.